# Codeception environment configuration not working

Tags: configuration, codeception, environments

Codeception: Configuration file(s) placed in tests/_envs are not working. I am trying to run my acceptance tests in multiple environments (ex. dev, qa, staging, prod). So I  have setup dev.yml, qa.yml, staging.yml and prod.yml files under tests/_env directory. Each of those separate environment I am overriding the WebDriver - url.

file - dev.yml

```
modules:
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'dev.mysite.local'
```

Then when I try to run the acceptance test suite using one of the environment, ex

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance --env dev
```

It doesn’t pull in the dev configuration, but instead uses the default configuration from acceptance.suite.yml file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the codeception/configuration.php file where a wrong regular expression has been used, which prevents .yml file from being loaded. However, dist.yml files loads just fine. They have already pushed a change for this bug.

In case you don't have this [changeset](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commit/18c831303aaccadb7e234531dc91611e32f4ae73), you can manually change it on your codeception/configuration.php file or simply use the dist.yml extension.

Wrong regex:

```
$envFiles = Finder::create()
        ->files()
        ->name('*{.dist}.yml')
        ->in($path)
        ->depth('< 1');
```

Correction:

```
    $envFiles = Finder::create()
        ->files()
        ->name('*.yml')
        ->in($path)
        ->depth('< 1');
```

Thanks to [sjableka for the answer posted on the Codeception repo](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2229#issuecomment-128947184).